# MySQL: How to apply payments against a Job record

Tags: java, mysql, database, user-interface

I have two tables in a MySQL database: jobs and payment. I would like to process payments for each job individually via a Java GUI Swing Form. But I am unsure how to search for the corresponding job to pay using jobID. So any supporting coding is welcome and will greatly help.

Here is the structure of my tables.

```
Table:   Jobs  
Columns: JobID,  CustomerID,  StartDate,  JobPriority, JobStatus
         , EndDate, NumberOfTasks, Payment 

Table:     Payment 
Columns:   JobID, paymenttype, amount, card details
```

I want to extract the job information and display it and only if it is not paid and the jobstatus is "complete". Then accept payment details via cash card etc.. Below is a snippet of code from another section to demonstrate. I want to create something similar, but using a jobID instead. ie Pass in a job id and find the job details.

```
public void updateAccountName(String name, String phone, String address, String number)throws SQLException{
    String qry = "UPDATE CustomerAccount SET AccountName = \""+name+
                   "\", Address = \""+address+
                   "\", Phone = \""+phone+
                   "\" WHERE AccountNumber= \"" +number + "\"";

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;

    try{
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("URL");
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(qry);
        stmt.executeUpdate();

    } finally{
        if (stmt != null) try{ stmt.close();} catch (SQLException se) {}
        if (con != null) try{ con.close();} catch (SQLException se) {}
    }
    notifyListeners();
}
```

Comment: I think you could extract all unpaid jobs with sql like: SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE payment="unpaid" AND status="complete"

Comment: What does the Jobs.Payment column represent? Also, that sql is vulnerable to [sql injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html). Always [parameterize queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html).